# Streaming live video from a camera to a display using two arduino UNOs

Tags: arduino, camera, video

My question is pretty much in the title. Is it possible to send live video from a camera connected to one arduino uno, to another arduino uno with a monitor connected? (Via wifi, Bluetooth, radio, etc.) Will they have enough processing power and can any simple data transfer methods allow such large amounts of data? Please inform me on the details if this is possible, or if not possible, explain other ways using a similar setup.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your best bet would be to take out the Arduino from the equation, **especially** when sending and receiving data wirelessly. Two FPGA's could easily do the job, but they are not the cheapest, also there would be a lot of _programming_ and _learning_ because FPGA's don't work exactly like microcontrollers.

Answer (score 2):

Possible yes - practical very difficult. 
In theory you can send video, but the uno has very little processing power which means that the resolution and framerate you will achieve is probably unsatisfying. I'm not currently aware of any libraries supporting this, so if you did go for this solution you will have to do a lot of programming your self.
I would recommend you to use a raspberry pi instead, or similar. This has the advantage of you being able to use a lot of ready made streaming library. In the end this will take you a lot further much quicker.

Check this out to get inspired: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Video-Streaming/